# Does my new shower need a dedicated vent?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I am adding a shower to my existing 1/2 bath. to do the plumbing I can do the p trap and go straight over to the main house drain. Do I still have to have a vent??

Comment: How far is it from the trap to the main drain?  When you say "main drain", do you mean the "main stack" (where the main vent is)?  what size pipe is the main vent? How many other; and what type of, fixtures are already using it? what size drain pipe are you using for the shower?

Comment: yes main stack, there are a tub and 2 toilet using it now. 2" drain pipe

Comment: it goes down and then over about 5 or 6 feet

Comment: Can you provide some photos?  Is it a 4" stack, or 3"?

Answer (score 1):

Local codes may be different in each area. Check with your local building inspector. If there is already a vent because you have a sink and toilet, you could possibly tie into that for drain and vent. 
I remodeled recently and moved the kitchen from one side of the house to the other. Where I ended up placing the sink and dishwasher, was on the same wall as a bathroom I had installed 3 years ago, on the opposite side. This allowed me to tie into the drain and water in the wall, which already had a vent stack. Inspector was perfectly satisfied with this setup. 
So again, I would ask your local inspector. A permit is most likely needed, and would have to have an inspection for rough and final. Best to get the vent issue taken care of before rough inspection.

Comment: My paragraph and punctuation is correct. Whoever tried to edit it made it no longer make sense.